# Share the same QGraphicsEffect for many QGraphicsItems

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, reference, qgraphicsitem

### What I do:

I am creating a new **QGraphicsEffect** in the constructor of my View (QMainWindow):

```
QGraphicsBlurEffect *m_blurEffect = new QGraphicsBlurEffect(this);
QGraphicsScene *m_scene = new GameGraphicsScene();
QGraphicsView *m_graphicsView = new QGraphicsView();
m_graphicsView->setScene(m_scene);
```

Then I create several **QGraphicsItems**:

```
QGraphicsItem *item = new QGraphicsItem;
item->setGraphicsEffect(m_blurEffect); //<< This Line is where I need help
m_scene->addItem(item);
```

I want all these QGraphicsItems to share the same **QGraphicsBlurEffect**, so that I can *easily toggle enabled/disabled* by calling

```
m_blurEffect->setEnabled(false); //(true)
```

in the View (where they get the pointer to the effect from.

---

### What it does:

It appears that only one of these items contains the pointer, after the creating-progress.
I used qDebug to show me if the pointer to m_blurEffect is correct after a new QGraphicsItem is created

```
for(...)
{
   QGraphicsItem *item= new TileGraphicsItem();
   item->setGraphicsEffect(m_blurEffect);
   qDebug() << m_blurEffect << tileItem->graphicsEffect();
}
```

The output is correct, something like:

> qDebug(): 
>   [...]

QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120) QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120)

QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120) QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120)

QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120) QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120)

QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120) QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139fe120)

> [...]

For more checking I let qDebug tell me the reference to m_blurEffect again, when I'm hovering my mouse over the Items.
The result shows, that all of them have empty pointers

```
qDebug() << graphicsEffect();
```

> ```
> QObject(0x0)
> ```

except the last item that was created, it contains the right reference (QGraphicsBlurEffect(0x139ce140) in my case).

---

### So what can I do?

I want to achieve, that they all share the correct reference to one QGraphicsEffect* object that I created before they existed.

If necessary I can give further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsEffect`s cannot be shared between several graphics items. You need to create an object of graphics effect for each graphics item. See the documentation of `QGraphicsItem::setGraphicsEffect`:

> If *effect* is the installed on a different item, setGraphicsEffect() will remove the effect from the item and install it on this item. QGraphicsItem takes ownership of *effect*.